# Drawing a flag in LaTeX Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, html

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usepackage[html]{xcolor} 

\definecolor{rot}{HTML}{e40303}
\definecolor{xorange}{HTML}{ff8c00}
\definecolor{gelb}{HTML}{ffed00}
\definecolor{gruen}{HTML}{008026}
\definecolor{blau}{HTML}{004dff}
\definecolor{lilla}{HTML}{750787}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.026458cm,y=0.026458cm]
\fill[fill=rot](0,0)rectangle(750,70);
\fill[fill=xorange](0,0)rectangle(750,140);
\fill[fill=gelb](0,0)rectangle(750,210);
\fill[fill=gruen](0,0)rectangle(750,280);
\fill[fill=blau](0,0)rectangle(750,350);
\fill[fill=lilla](0,0)rectangle(750,420);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I don't know why it doesn't do what I wanted it to do. Hopefully some of you can help?

[image: Regenbogenflagge]

Kind regards!

Comment: Could you please detail more what you wanted to do? At least to me, it is not clear at all.

Comment: I think we should properly ask this question as *Drawing the gay pride flag*. By the way it is also already in the TikZ manual. Search for `pride`

Comment: @percusse to clarify, a gradient version is included in the current manual. this is stepwise.

Comment: If you want to preserve the original golden ratio of the rainbow flag, you should use 77 in place of 70 as rectangle height.

Comment: @SeanAllred It is not a country flag. You can spot rainbow everywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some comments :

1. `xcolor` is loaded by `tikz`, so don't reload it again,
2. use capitals in color numbers,
3. your last rectangle overlap the previous ones,
4. you can make it shorter using `foreach`.

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\definecolor{rot}{HTML}{E40303}
\definecolor{xorange}{HTML}{FF8C00}
\definecolor{gelb}{HTML}{FFED00}
\definecolor{gruen}{HTML}{008026}
\definecolor{blau}{HTML}{004DFF}
\definecolor{lilla}{HTML}{750787}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.026458cm,y=0.026458cm]
    \foreach[count=\i] \col in {lilla,blau,gruen,gelb,xorange,rot}
      \fill[\col] (0,70*\i) rectangle +(750,70);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Let's go :) `\tikz\foreach[count=\i]~in{E40303,FF8C00,FFED00,008026,004DFF,750787}\definecolor{temp}{HTML}{~}\fill[temp](0,70*\i pt)rectangle+(750 pt,70 pt);
`

Comment: @percusse `\tikz\foreach[count=\i]~in{E40303,FF8C00,FFED00,008026,004DFF,750787}\definecolor{t}{HTML}{~}\fill[t]rectangle(750pt,70*(7-\i pt);`, your turn ;)

Comment: @Kpym what does the "(0,70*\i) " make?

Comment: @Dr.HenrietteB.Fröhlich The `(0,70*\i)` sets the starting coordinate for each bar of the flag starting at the bottom: (0,70) then (0,140), then (0,210) etc.

Comment: Cheating just to pass the turn :P `\tikz\foreach[count=\i]~in{E40303,FF8C00,FFED00,008026,004DFF,750787}\definecolor t{HTML}{~}\fill[t]rectangle(750pt,70*(7-\i pt);`

Comment: @percusse Cheating is part of the business ;) `\tikz\foreach[count=\i]~in{E40303,FF8C00,FFED00,008026,004DFF,750787}\definecolor t{HTML}~\fill[t]rectangle(750pt,70*(7-\i pt);`

Comment: OK I give you golden ratio then :P `\tikz\foreach[count=\i]~in{E40303,FF8C00,FFED00,008026,004DFF,750787}\definecolor t{HTML}~\fill[t](0,\i)|-(15,\i+1.545)|-(0,\i);` ... Aargh I gave away the trophy haha I should have thought about it anyway let's see if you can find it :)

Answer (score 9):

The previous color is overwritten by the next larger rectangle, probably you want something like:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\definecolor{lila}{HTML}{8800bb}
\definecolor{blau}{HTML}{0000FF}
\definecolor{hellblau}{HTML}{88bbdd}
\definecolor{gruen}{HTML}{66bb44}   
\definecolor{gelb}{HTML}{FFee00} 
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FF4411}
\definecolor{rot}{HTML}{FF1100}   

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.026458cm,y=0.026458cm]
\fill[fill=lila](0,0)rectangle(750,70);
\fill[fill=blau](0,70)rectangle(750,140);
\fill[fill=hellblau](0,140)rectangle(750,210);
\fill[fill=gruen](0,210)rectangle(750,280);   
\fill[fill=gelb](0,280)rectangle(750,350);    
\fill[fill=orange](0,350)rectangle(750,420);
\fill[fill=rot](0,420)rectangle(750,490);   
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Remark for `xcolor` 2007/02/21 v2.11

This version has a bug with the effect that the lowercase `f` does not work inside the values for the color model `HTML`.

Workarounds:

- Using uppercase letters. Example: `\definecolor{gelb}{HTML}{FFEE00}`
- After package `xcolor` is loaded, the macro `\@hex@@Hex` needs to be patched, which converts lowercase hex digits to uppercase hex digits, needed for TeX's hex syntax with the double quote:

  ```
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \makeatletter
  \patchcmd\@hex@@Hex{f\else}{F\else}{}{}
  \makeatother
  ```

Answer (score 6):

In case you would like the flag to fly...

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,positioning}

\definecolor{rot}{HTML}{e40303}
\definecolor{xorange}{HTML}{FF8c00}
\definecolor{gelb}{HTML}{FFed00}
\definecolor{gruen}{HTML}{008026}
\definecolor{blau}{HTML}{004dFF}
\definecolor{lilla}{HTML}{750787}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.026458cm, y=0.026458cm, tape bend height=20, shape=tape, text width=750, minimum height=70, inner sep=0pt, node distance=-1pt]
  \node (rot) [fill=rot] {};
  \node (oren) [fill=xorange, below=of rot] {};
  \node (melyn) [fill=gelb, below=of oren] {};
  \node (gwyrdd) [fill=gruen, below=of melyn] {};
  \node (glas) [fill=blau, below=of gwyrdd] {};
  \node [fill=lilla, below=of glas] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: flying pride]

Or, more concisely using a `\foreach` loop:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,positioning}

\definecolor{rot}{HTML}{e40303}
\definecolor{xorange}{HTML}{FF8c00}
\definecolor{gelb}{HTML}{FFed00}
\definecolor{gruen}{HTML}{008026}
\definecolor{blau}{HTML}{004dFF}
\definecolor{lilla}{HTML}{750787}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.026458cm, y=0.026458cm, tape bend height=20, shape=tape, text width=750, minimum height=70, inner sep=0pt, node distance=-1pt]
  \node (rot) [fill=rot] {};
  \foreach \i [remember=\i as \j (initially rot)] in {xorange,gelb,gruen,blau,lilla}
  \node (\i) [fill=\i, below=of \j] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Adjusting the height a little:

[image: fflag pride 2]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,positioning}

\definecolor{rot}{HTML}{e40303}
\definecolor{xorange}{HTML}{FF8c00}
\definecolor{gelb}{HTML}{FFed00}
\definecolor{gruen}{HTML}{008026}
\definecolor{blau}{HTML}{004dFF}
\definecolor{lilla}{HTML}{750787}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.026458cm, y=0.026458cm, tape bend height=20, shape=tape, minimum width=750, minimum height=100, inner sep=0pt, node distance=-1pt]
  \node (rot) [fill=rot] {};
  \node (oren) [fill=xorange, below=of rot] {};
  \node (melyn) [fill=gelb, below=of oren] {};
  \node (gwyrdd) [fill=gruen, below=of melyn] {};
  \node (glas) [fill=blau, below=of gwyrdd] {};
  \node [fill=lilla, below=of glas] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```